# save image view as binary data in Core Data (swift4)

Tags: ios, core-data, imageview, swift4, binary-data

I am trying to save a image view to binary data. The code compiles but when the button is pressed a sigabbt error occurs. The image view has a image in it. I don't know what is going on. Its just the image view is not saving.

```
  class editVCViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageV: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var theView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var mattBarnes: UITextField!
    @IBAction func magicJohnson(_ sender: Any) {

        let photo = self.imageV.image
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo!)

            if cdHandler.saveObject(pic:  data!){

          }}

}




        class func saveObject(pic: Data) -> Bool {
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)

        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        managedObject.setValue(pic, forKey:"binaryAttribute")

        do {
            try context.save()
            return true

        } catch {
            return false

        }
    }
```

Comment: It might help if you would say what line in this code causes the crash. For what it's worth, everywhere you use a `!` in this code, you are specifically asking for a crash if anything unexpected happens.

Comment: @TomHarrington this is the era message I am getting in the log file Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<User 0x604000288750> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity User is not key value coding-compliant for the key "binaryAttribute".'

Comment: That seems pretty clear, it says that `User` doesn't have an attribute with that name.